# COSMOS road bike? Identify my frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

[image: Vintage Cosmos road bike]

it is a vintage Cosmos World Champion road bike. 
Frame height is 57 cm / 22.44 inches (measured from the center of the crankshaft to the seatpost).

Frame uses Columbus tubing. Components:

- Selle Italia Turbo 1985 WC  "World Championship" leather saddle.
- 3ttt "3T" Triple T  Super Competizione / Racing Team Service  steerer.
- Brev. Campagnolo Front dropout.
- Columbus rear dropout.
- Weinmann Carrera 1st generation brakes (Red emblem).
- Gipiemme Sprint Pedals.
- 1st generation Dura-Ace front derailleur.
- Shimano RD-6401 , 600 Ultegra rear derailleur.
- Shimano FC-1050, 105 crankset.
- Shimano SL-1055, 105SC (7sp) shifters. (Band On / Clamp on)
- Shimano BL-1055 / 105SC  brake levers.
- Mavic MA 2 rims.
- Ciclolinea 80's bar end plugs.

Comment: Is that round black thing on the quill stem a bell?

Answer (score 5):

Cosmos is a South African manufacturer. I believe they hand built good quality road and track frames but have long been out of business. You will probably find an enthusiast to tell you more on http://bikehub.co.za/  Nice bike!

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Good answer - thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 3):

Late reply on this..

Cosmos was made in Vereeninging, South Africa. The master frame buidler's name was Wimpie. I cannot recall his surname as i met him once when i was 16 - in 1991. At the time my dad had them build me a custom Reynolds 753 bike - which i still have today and actually started restoring a couple of weeks ago. I can also not recall the actual company name. Cosmos bikes at the time competed with Hansom, Alpina, etc. bikes. The Reynolds tubing mine was made with is seriously strong. Even now after 27 years, no rust (apart from superficial rust spots, but nothing a piece of sandpaper did not take off.

If you still have the bike, enjoy it.